# Sublime Text 3 package cannot be found when listing packages

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, package-control

I updated from ST2 to ST3 and transferred all my packages over to ST3. All of my packages seem to work but when I try to view my packages through Tools>Packages I don't see anything. I'm also given an error message of "“Emmet” can’t be found." when trying to list any of my installed packages. Has anyone come across this? I found a patch on Github but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this guide](http://wesbos.com/migrating-to-sublime-text-3/) when I originally migrated and all my packages worked fine. I ended doing this process again and transferred all my ST2 packages over again. Everything looks good so far and I can list and view packages.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of transferring you might need to reinstall all of the packages. I'm not sure, but this could be caused by differences between the versions.